# Rubymine ruby under ubuntu windows 10 copies full C drive in background

Tags: rubygems, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rubymine

I'm using Windows 10 and Rubymine 2019.3, and WSL Ubuntu. If I run everything from the console it runs fine, what I want to do is use the run/debug setup from the IDE.

Since I'm using the remote ruby connection for this, when I set up the environment it says **"Downloading gems"** and after that it copies the whole C drive. I believe this happens because it's mounted by the default by the wsl and when it tries to download it makes a copy of the file system.

[image]
Does anyone knows why this happens? And also is it subscribed as a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-25284 and should be fixed in RubyMine 2019.3.2 Preview, for now you can try 2019.3.2 RC: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Early+Access+Program

Please check also the comment from the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-25284#focus=streamItem-27-3880211.0-0